# select combo box based on get value

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I'm using search with combo box

Here is my combo box source code

```html
<select name="salary" class="styled">
  <option selected="selected" value=''>Any</option>
  <option value="10000">10,000</option>
  <option value="20000">20,000</option>
  <option value="30000">30,000</option>
  <option value="40000">40,000</option>
  <option value="50000">50,000</option>
  <option value="60000">60,000</option>
  <option value="70000">70,000</option>
  <option value="80000">80,000</option>
  <option value="90000">90,000</option>
  <option value="100000">100,000</option>
  <option value="110000">110,000</option>
  <option value="120000">120,000</option>
  <option value="130000">130,000</option>
  <option value="140000">140,000</option>
  <option value="150000">150,000</option>
</select>
```

I would like to select value based on `$salary=$_GET['salary'];` if `$salary` empty I need to select first one as selected

Comment: go and accept some answers from previous questions you've asked, if they provided a correct solution

Comment: Are <option> values a fixed number of items or are they dynamic (fetched from DB, may increase daily etc)?

Comment: @Idriz Šunja not fixed, it is fech from MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this on creation...[not tested]

```
<?php 
$options = array(
 '10000' => '10,000',
...
 '150000' => '150,000'
); //From MySQL

array_unshift($options, '' => 'Any');

$salary = isset($_GET['salary'])?$_GET['salary']:'';
?>

<select name="salary" class="styled">
<?php foreach ($options as $value=>$text){ ?>
   <option <?php if($value == $salary){echo 'selected="selected"'; }?> value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: there is no `<option selected="selected" value=''>Any</option>` in database :(

Answer (score 2):

To set a default value for an HTML select element, you need to give the appropriate `<option>` element the `selected` attribute. It would look like this:

```
<option value='50000' selected='selected'>50,000</option>
```

In your PHP code, you would add this by setting a string for each option, to either `"selected='selected'"` or blank, depending on whether that option is the one you want to have selected.

This is obviously far easier to put into a loop rather than writing the same code twenty times, so you would need to rewrite your output to create a loop for creating your options.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want that if the person doesn't select any thing you want 10000 to be automatically selected for him. And I also assume that the options in the select list are static. So..

```
<?php
if($_GET['salary']=='')
$salary = 10000;
else
$salary = $_GET['salary'];
?>
```